# Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at TrafficLight.v(59) near text "endcase"; expecting "end"

Tags: verilog

I am new to veriloghdl and I am getting this error in verilog hdl

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at TrafficLight.v(59) near text "endcase";  expecting "end"
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

my code is

```
module TrafficLight(t, state, next_state, clk, out);

input t, clk;
output out;
localparam s0=3'b000, s1=3'b001, s2=3'b010, s3=3'b011, s4=3'b100, s5=3'b101;
reg[2:0] state, next_state, tt;
always@(posedge clk)
    begin
    case(state)
        3'b000:
            if(tt < 5)
                next_state = s0;
            else
                begin
                next_state = s1;
                assign out [5:0] = 6'b100001;
                end
        3'b001:
            if(tt < 1)
                next_state = s1;
            else
            begin
                next_state = s2;
                assign out [5:0] = 6'b010001;
            end
        3'b010:
            if(tt < 1)
                next_state = s2;
            else
            begin
                next_state = s3;
                assign out [5:0] = 6'b001001;
            end
        3'b011:
            if(tt < 5)
                next_state = s3;
            else
            begin
                next_state = s4;
                assign out [5:0] = 6'b001100;
            end
        3'b100:
            if(tt < 1)
                next_state = s4;
            else
            begin
                next_state = s5;
                assign out [5:0] = 6'b001010;
            end
        3'b101:
            if(tt < 1)
                next_state = s0;
            else
                begin
                next_state = s5;
                assign out [5:0] = 6'b001001;
                end
    endcase


    always@(posedge clk);
        begin
        state = next_state;
        tt = tt - 1;
        end

endmodule
```

The error occured I think on the lines endcase and endmodule. I think I would have to close them with something.

Comment: And you're missing an `end` to go with your first `begin`.

Comment: how can I fix this error now appearing after I have applied those fixes Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at TrafficLight.v(62) near text "always";  expecting a description

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in your code -

You missed the "end" after the "endcase" statement. The end is required for the begin block just before the case statement.

You have added ";" in the always block declaration.

```
always@(posedge clk);
    begin
    state = next_state;
    tt = tt - 1;
    end
```

There is no need of an ";" in the always block.

```
module TrafficLight(t, state, next_state, clk, out);

input t, clk;
output out;
localparam s0=3'b000, s1=3'b001, s2=3'b010, s3=3'b011, s4=3'b100, s5=3'b101;
reg[2:0] state, next_state, tt;
```

In the above snippet I see that you have added "state" and "next_state" as ports to the module but haven't assigned any direction to them. Either remove them as ports or make them as "input" or "output".

You would also need to remove the "assign" statement when driving the out reg. Since it is inside a procedural block you don't need an "assign" here.

You can find all the updates to your code [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6GWs)

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions and I am still left with this erro

Comment: This answer will fix the compiling errors, but there are still runtime issues. Synchronous logic should be assigned with non-blocking (`<=`). `next_state` probably should be combinational, which means it should be in an `always @*` block. Ideally `out` should be synchrnous, so maybe change the first always bock to `@*` and in this block change `out` to `next_out`, then assign `out <= next_out` in the remaining `@(posedge clk)`. Also, input `t` is never used.

Comment: Yes Greg. I intended to solve the compilation errors only. Thank you for pointing that out. Clearly there are a few updates required to resolve the run time errors as well.