# Error (10278): Verilog HDL Port Declaration error at TrafficLight.v(5): input port "t" cannot be declared with type "<a variable data type, e.g. reg>"

Tags: verilog

verilog error while I try to implement a traffic light system with six states I wanted to display lights red, green, yellow on the led display of ALTERA DE2 board

code is as below

```
module TrafficLight(clk, t, out);
    input clk, t;
    output out;
    localparam s0=3'b000, s1=3'b001, s2=3'b010, s3=3'b011, s4=3'b100, s5=3'b101;
    reg[2:0] state, next_state, t;

    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
        state = next_state;
        t = t - 1;
    end

    always@(t or state)
         begin
         case(state)
              3'b000:
                    if(t < 5)
                         next_state = s0;
                    else
                    begin
                         next_state = s1;
                         assign out [5:0] = 6'b100001;
                    end
              3'b001:
                    if(t < 1)
                         next_state = s1;
                    else
                    begin
                         next_state = s2;
                         assign out [5:0] = 6'b010001;
                    end
              3'b010:
                    if(t < 1)
                         next_state = s2;
                    else
                    begin
                         next_state = s3;
                         assign out [5:0] = 6'b001001;
                    end
              3'b011:
                    if(t < 5)
                         next_state = s3;
                    else
                    begin
                         next_state = s4;
                         assign out [5:0] = 6'b001100;
                    end
              3'b100:
                    if(t < 1)
                         next_state = s4;
                    else
                    begin
                         next_state = s5;
                         assign out [5:0] = 6'b001010;
                    end
              3'b101:
                    if(t < 1)
                         next_state = s0;
                    else
                    begin
                         next_state = s5;
                         assign out [5:0] = 6'b001001;
                    end
                endcase
            end
    endmodule
```

What is wrong with this code can anyone fix it?

Comment: I have already pointed out various issues in your code in the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437405/error-10170-verilog-hdl-syntax-error-at-trafficlight-v59-near-text-endcase) question. Anyway, you can find an updated version [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6GWs)

Comment: If `t` is an input, then you cannot assign it. `output out;` should be `output reg [5:0] out;`

Answer (score 0):

In Verilog an input cannot be a `reg`, as the error message says. Don't declare `t` as a `reg` by changing this line:

```
reg[2:0] state, next_state, t;
```

to this:

```
reg[2:0] state, next_state;
```

Comment: We cannot even drive an input value as well - `t = t - 1;`
Also, there is no need to use `assign` in a procedural block - `assign out [5:0] = 6'b001001;`

Comment: @RahulBehl In fact one _should not_ use an assign statement in a procedural block. It is legal but (a) means something weird and (b) is deprecated.

Comment: Yes you are right about it. Though `VCS 2014.10` reports a compile time error if we do continuous assignment in a procedural block. So probably they are not legal now.